# Select min date with another table columns

Tags: mysql

I want to select last created field for user rate. Below are links to screenshots of tables from which i try to select data.

[rates](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7lA9Z.png)

[fields](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JJJ6B.png)

My query is

```
select fields.content, min(fields.creation_date) as created
from fields
  left join rates
    on fields.rate_id=rates.rate_id
where rates.user_id=4
group by fields.content
```

and result is

<kbd>content</kbd>              <kbd>created</kbd>                            
<kbd>dolor sit</kbd>             <kbd>2016-10-28 19:33:50</kbd>       
<kbd>lorem ipsum</kbd>      <kbd>2016-10-28 19:33:49</kbd>

How to modify my query to have result like below?

<kbd>content</kbd>              <kbd>created</kbd>                            
<kbd>lorem ipsum</kbd>      <kbd>2016-10-28 19:33:49</kbd>

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `order by` and `limit`:

```
select f.*
from fields f left join
     rates r
     on f.rate_id = r.rate_id
where r.user_id = 4
order by f.creation_date asc
limit 1;
```

Note that if there are ties (two records with the same `creation_date`), then this will choose one arbitrarily.

Also, I suspect that you want:

```
select f.*
from rates r left join
     fields f
     on f.rate_id = r.rate_id
where r.user_id = 4
order by f.creation_date asc
limit 1;
```

In your version, the `left join` is not necessary -- it is turned to an inner join by the `where` clause.  Further, I would expect `f.rate_id` to always match `r.rate_id`, especially if you have a properly declared foreign key relationship.  This will return a row even if there are no records in `fields` (which appears to be your intention).